# Javascript Input Text control

Tags: javascript

I need to do a text input validation in javascript with the below rules.

Could you please let me know the regular expression for this?

the Text Input should be exactly 8  long, and it should meet the following conditions:

- Starts with 3 letters
- Then and Underscore
  and ends with 4 Digits

I have tried this :  `/^[a-z A-Z]{3} - [0-9]{4} *$/`
but it did not work
Thank you

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: It should be `/^[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{4}$/` The spaces have meaning in the regex, see https://regex101.com/r/fGFlcv/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you make your comment into an answer. You have Samid's problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces in a regex have meaning, so you have te omit them from the pattern. You are also matching a hyphen instead of an underscore.

This character class `[a-z A-Z]{3}` can for example also match 3 spaces.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{4}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGFlcv/1)